# Get oauth2 access_token owner email address in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, sinatra, google-contacts-api

I am successfully using **Oauth2 gem** to get an **access tokens** from Google accounts. But I want to get the **email address** which produced the token (I mean if I used this account "myemail@gmail.com" to get the access_token, how can I know the email address from the token?). Or can I get the email while obtaining the token?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can get that email with the response for any API call. For contacts API, by example, there is an entry called `author` in the response: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts

Anyway, I'm not sure which gem you're using. You can use [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2), [doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) or [cloudsponge](http://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/ruby).